# Using @reboot with cron

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, raspberry-pi

I am attempting to enable cron to run this python script on reboot.

I have already tried both the GUI and script file version of cron, and neither will run the script, while if I run it in terminal, it works. I have also tried to put it into some start up scripts as well, but had no luck.

(OnReboot.py) Python code, located in the home folder

```
import subprocess
firefox_path = '/usr/bin/iceweasel'
cmdline = [firefox_path]
with open('url_list.txt', 'r') as url_file:
    for url in url_file:
        cmdline.append(url)
subprocess.Popen(cmdline)
```

Cron code

```
@reboot python ./OnReboot.py
```

I expect that when the Pi restarts, the python code will be ran automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about `@reboot`, but you aren't using it!

If you want your script to run on reboot, specify `@reboot` instead of a time specification in your crontab, e.g.

```
@reboot python ./OnReboot.py
```

Additionally, a relative path like `./OnReboot.py` may not work correctly in a cronjob, as cron's working directory may not be what you expect. Use an absolute path (e.g. `/path/to/OnReboot.py`) for best results.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, in cron, I have it typed as @reboot and it still does not work, I just mistyped it in the question.